# It doesn't find messages node.js mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have really weird error with finding messages in my chat app... It seems to be all good, but it doesn't find messages.... When I do and query with just first condition it works well. Here are photos of code:

1. Console.log
2. MongoDB console
3. Message finding code with one of the solution proposed here

[image: console log]

[image: MongoDB console]

[image: Message finding with objectid]

Comment: just cast your `req.user._id` and `req.body.id` to be `ObjectId`.

Comment: How to do it? I haven't done it yet

Comment: You just need to require the ObjectId function from your mongo. 

    `ObjectId = require('mongodb').ObjectID;`

Then you can use it like that: 

   `ObjectId(req.body.id)`

Comment: Still ain't working ☹️☹️

Comment: you need to cast boh req.body.id and req.user._id

Comment: still ain't working

Comment: Can I do two and queries? Because when I put just and query with first condition it works so maybe if it is possible I could do second and query with second condition?

Comment: yes you can do two queries or just change the `$and` to `$or` in that case, if you want to share exactly what logic you want we can simplify your query as now it uses "unusual" syntax.